# How to get the crop coordinates of an image before upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, crop, jcrop

I am trying to get `Jcrop` plugin work after user selects an image by clicking on the browse button, we can load the preview of an image by using `FileReader()`, I am able to show the preview but when I am initializing `Jcrop` on `change` event of the browse button, it doesn't work. Below is the code.

**Form**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imageInput" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imageInput").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
    $("#blah").Jcrop();
});
```

In the above Javascript code when I am adding `$("#blah").Jcrop();`, the preview doesn't work and I get a black line instead. I have created a Fiddle to demonstrate the same http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/8230/

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `Jcrop` call inside `FileReader.onload` callback like this (I tried it in FF inside your fiddle and it works fine)

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $("#blah").Jcrop();
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imageInput").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```